# How does a neutron have more mass than a hydrogen atom's isotope (Specifically deuterium)?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons

A hydrogen atom weighs 1.00794 u ± 0.00001 u. The mass of a neutron is slightly above it, at 1.00866491600(43) u‎. I'm wondering, how does a neutron weigh more than itself plus 2 extra particles, as we see in hydrogens weight?

Edit: I was unaware that I should have mentioned the hydrogens isotope, deuterium, since hydrogen atoms do not have a neutron as Ghost pointed out in his answer below.

Comment: Looks like I forgot the very basics, wowza. Thank you Ghost for pointing this out, very helpful! :)

Comment: This is a very confused question. A neutron cannot logically weigh more than itself.

Comment: @annav Exactly. I thought it was present in a hydrogen atom, but as Ghost pointed out, a neutron is not present in a hydrogen atom. So technically, that answered my question and cleared up my confusion.

Comment: Can you clarify the question in the body, because it still doesn't make sense as written.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a misconception in your question, specifically:

> how does a neutron weigh more than itself plus 2 extra particles

It doesn't.

A hydrogen atom is composed only of a proton and an electron, but no neutron.  Hydrogen is shown diagrammatically shown below:

[image]

*[Image Source](http://www.chemicalelements.com/elements/h.html)*

If a neutron were included, then it becomes the isotope of hydrogen, deuterium, which 
according to the [Commission of Isotopic Abundances and Atomic Weights](http://www.ciaaw.org/hydrogen.htm), has an atomic mass greater than a neutron itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up! Very helpful! :)

Comment: You are very welcome - am glad I could help!

Comment: This answer does not clear up the confusion of the question but increases it by introducing deuterim

Comment: @annav I reworded it to clarify what I am getting at.

Answer (score 7):

Free neutrons are unstable, and decay to a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino with a half life of about 10 minutes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron

In most cases, the electron escapes but the proton captures another electron from its environment, making a hydrogen atom composed of one proton, one electron (and no neutrons.) In some rare cases the electron fails to escape from the proton and the two particles become a hydrogen atom directly (in these cases all the excess energy is carried off by the antineutrino.)

Given that the decay from a neutron to a hydrogen atom is spontaneous (releases energy) it is unsurprising that a neutron weighs more than a hydrogen atom, in accordance with the relativistic mass-energy relation E=mc^2.